# undefined method `path' with csv import via sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, sidekiq

I am trying to import a large csv via `sidekiq`. But i am facing problem.

I wrote `import` method in my controller.

```
  def import
   Importcsv.perform_async(params[:file])
   redirect_to calendars_path, notice: "Calendar imported."
  end
```

And Worker code is here.

```
class Importcsv
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  sidekiq_options queue: "high"

 def perform(file)
   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|
   calendar = find_by_id(row['id']) || new
     calendar.attributes = row.to_hash
     calendar.save
   end
 end
end
```

But i got this error `undefined method`path' for "/tmp/RackMultipart20150928-8812-sgwsm5":String`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by passing single row, e.g.

```
CSV.foreach(params[:file].path, headers: true) do |row|
  attrs ={name: row[0]} 
  Importcsv.perform_async(attrs)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You error log indicates, you are trying to get `path` from an instance of `String`. You can try this code:

```
def perform(file)
  file = file.path if file.is_a?(File)
  CSV.foreach(file, headers: true) do |row|
    # ...
  end
end
```

This way you can accept both `String` and `File` parameters in this method. Also please note, when working with Sidekiq you cannot pass `File` as a parameter. Read about it in more details [here](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Best-Practices#1-make-your-job-parameters-small-and-simple).

Comment: Now  undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion

Comment: Did you restart worker? There is no possibility left for this error

Comment: yes but now,  no implicit conversion of nil into String

Comment: I want to ask - its work fine when am not using Sidekiq

Comment: It happens sometimes. Common source of errors are parameters. (1) Are you sure params[:file] is not empty? The best way to test is Importcsv.new.perform(params[:file]) (2) Is it a string. Try to convert it to string using to_s.

Comment: I solved this issue - but the problem is in path, that how we can provide a path. I think this error "/tmp/RackMultipart20150928-8812-sgwsm5":String` is because - when Sidekiq start processing he is unable to find that path